# Spock: is it possible to specify where to create tempDir?

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

There is a useful annotation @TempDir in spock which helps us to create temporary folder and automatically delete it. Full name of annotation class looks like:

**com.github.goldin.spock.extensions.tempdir.TempDir**

It usually create temp folder in the folder which is defined as TMP environment variable. A question is: is it possible to specify folder where to create temp folder somehow?

Comment: Is it impossible to override `java.io.tmpdir` with System.setProperty("java.io.tmpdir", "/tmp"); in `setup` method and set it back to original value in `cleanup` method ?

Comment: Its possible. But this looks like a change that may affect other simultaneously running tasks on the same instance. For example, if we run this test on TeamCity this may cause many issues with other build  executions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combinaison of `@RestoreSystemProperties` and `System.setProperty()` :

```
@RestoreSystemProperties
class TmpSpec extends Specification {

    def setup() {
        System.properties['java.io.tmpdir'] = "target/test"
        new File("target/test").mkdirs()
    }

    def "create a tmp file"() {
        given: "a tmp file"
            def file = File.createTempDir()

        expect:
            file.path.contains("target/test")

    }

}
```

You can create your own JUnit @Rule if you want more controls of this function during your tests.